# Having difficulties with regex

Tags: regex

Here is a string:

```
111A9d809d4712701eea0e9c2b2c143941ab000
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

The `9d809d4712701eea0e9c2b2c143941ab` is what changes every time but the `111A` and the `000` never change, I need to match the whole string, I tried googling but it is very hard to find answers to such specific needs, also can anyone please suggest me a web page or some program that will help me solve these kinds of problems.

Comment: where is the bold part?

Comment: Try `111A<b>9d809d4712701eea0e9c2b2c143941ab</b>000` if you want the characters in the middle to appear bold

Comment: You shouldn't try to find answers for specific regex, but try to learn it.

Comment: Your question is rather unclear. Are there always 32 characters in the middle? Can they contain `000` as a substring?

Comment: @chipChocolate.py I believe he is asking to be referred to a resource which can help him learn regex.

Comment: @DanVerdolino - Okay, everything you need to know about RegExp is well explained in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DRR9fOXkfRE) - by Derek Banas.

Comment: @chipChocolate.py actually, I might check that out myself...

Comment: Hey, guys, I think we shouldn't down vote. Regex are common trouble for many people

Comment: @DanVerdolino - You should, he has also given some Regex examples for emails, phone numbers, addresses and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

you are looking for:

```
111A[a-z0-9]{32}000
```

or for matching words only:

```
\b111A[a-z0-9]{32}000\b
```

or for matching whole strings only:

```
^111A[a-z0-9]{32}000$
```

or if middle part has random length, you may replace exact letters count (32) with "at least one" (+) or "may be have any count or does not have at all" (*):

```
111A[a-z0-9]+000
111A[a-z0-9]*000
\b111A[a-z0-9]+000\b
\b111A[a-z0-9]*000\b
^111A[a-z0-9]+000$
^111A[a-z0-9]*000$
```

Comment: \b stands for word boundary, e.g. "jhagfjdg111A...000" will not match, and ^ and $ are the beginning and the end of a str, "111A...000 111A...000 111A...000" will not match

Comment: Since its hexadecimal you should use `[a-f0-9]` and not allow the entire alphabet.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes not sure what TS exactly asked for

Answer (score 0):

Bold part?

Try

```
111A[a-z0-9]+000
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex:

```
/111A\w+?000/g
```

Or this one if your pattern has exactely 32 chars

```
/111A\w{32}000/g
```

Demo here: http://regex101.com/r/cQ7uF1/1

Comment: I think that you should match greedily here (remove the `?`) in case the inner string contains a `000`.

Comment: It'll fail either way with an inner string that contains `000`. Anyway this is probably a fixed length (32 chars) GUID so a `{32}` would solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'd advise you to buy a good book, for instance "**Mastering Regular Expressions", by Jeffrey Friedl** which is really good (http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596528126.do). Regex are extremely useful but also take some investment before you start seeing real benefits to your coding.

As for your regex, `/^111A[a-z0-9]+000$/` would do the trick (get rid of ^ and $ if you want to allow character before and after in the string, and depending on your programming language you may need to drop the surrounding slashes).

Comment: please mention, that this is js regex

Comment: It's pretty standard to write it that way if the language isn't specified. Most languages I know except maybe Java and C# allow this syntax.

Comment: Hello from python world. We do not enclose patterns into '/'

Comment: Well it's a shame, makes it look more snaky.